# How do I determine the time $t$ in which a function for the first time achieves the maximum and minimum value?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

So I have to use this function: $I(t) = 4.2 \times \sin (0.04  π  t) + 1.2$ and somehow find the maximum and minimum value, but I'm struggling to understand how.

Comment: What have you tried? You are more likely to get answers if you show us you made some efforts.

Comment: Is it $$I(t)=4.2\sin(0.04\pi t)+1.2$$?

Comment: #1 I'm pretty sure I have to find I'(t), I used d/dx to find the answer, but I'm lost when it comes to the process of getting there - how I'm supposed to find the answer on my own and what should I do next.

#2 Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$I(t)=4.2\sin(0.04\pi t)+1.2$

$\implies I'(t) = 0.168\pi\cdot\cos(0.04\pi t)$

Set $I'(t) = 0$

$0.168\pi\cdot\cos(0.04\pi t) = 0$

$\implies \cos(0.04\pi t)= 0$

$\implies 0.04 \pi t = \frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2$

NOTE: I am considering $0\ge t\ge2\pi$

$\implies t = \frac1{0.08}  $ or $t =\frac3{0.08}$

Now ;

$I''(t) = -0.00672\pi^2\sin(0.04\pi t)$

$I''(\frac1{0.08} )= -0.00672\pi^2\sin(\frac\pi2)$

$I''(\frac1{0.08} )= -0.00672\pi^2 \lt 0$

The second derivative is negative so the function has a maxima at $t = \frac1{0.08}$

$I''(\frac3{0.08}) =-0.00672\pi^2\sin(3\frac\pi2) $

$ I''(\frac3{0.08}) =0.00672\pi^2 \gt 0$

The second derivative is positive so the function has  a minima at $t = \frac{3}{0.08}$

Comment: Wow! This is really helpful, but can you explain the process of getting from I(t) to I'(t)?

Comment: You take the derivative w.r.t $t$ .You need to know the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and also [derivatives of common functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_of_computation). Once you have learnt that you can combine them . Khan Academy has some good classes on differentiation you should check them out.